# How to communicate with back button in android?

Tags: android

I made an app in which there is a progress dialogue. Whenever user sign in using his/her credentials progress dialogue shows logging in bt when someone presses back button after logging in It again shows the progress dialogue. So how to give clear screen to user when back button is pressed?

Comment: Are you launching a new activity, or just changing fragments?  If a new activity, finish() the old one.  If fragments, don't add the transaction to the back stack.

Comment: This link should help you :-
 https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: i am clicking on back button and it is showing progress dialogue , there is no logout button . When i am clicking on back button it is simply showing me back activity like we do in any app.

Comment: What do you want it to do when the user presses the back button?

Comment: Are you following a tutorial ? If yes, please post the link. 
Also try disabling the progress dialog after you open the activity to the login screen and dismiss it.

Comment: i guess you need to dismiss your progress dialogue

Comment: Please post the code. There is no way we can help with the little information you gave

Comment: I totally agree bt if i dismiss it after oncreate then it is showing me null object reference error  and i will post the code @vlatkozelka

Comment: please post your code so that we can help you.

Answer (score -1):

When you press back button add `pDialog.dismiss();`

```
private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

And back button code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    hideDialog();
}
```